# Convergence and absolute convergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{ \sin \pi x}{x^\alpha|1-x|^\beta}\text{d}x$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Please. I need help.

I have to study the convergence and the absolute convergence of $$\int_0^\infty \frac{ \sin \pi x}{x^\alpha|1-x|^\beta}\text{d}x,$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta>0$.

**EDIT:** Thanks to a comment below, I've already solved the absolute convergence.

Now, for the conditional convergence I tried to do it using integration by parts, choosing $$u=\frac{1}{x^\alpha|1-x|^\beta}$$ and $dv=\sin \pi x$ but I'm not sure that this can help. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the points $x=0,1,\infty$ separately. At $x=0$ the integrand behaviour is $x^{1-\alpha}$, at $x=1$ we get $x^{1-\beta}$, and as $x\to\infty$, it is like $x^{-\alpha-\beta}$. This means that the integral is absolutely convergent if and only if
$$
\max\{\alpha,\beta\}<2\quad\textrm{and}\quad \alpha+\beta>1.
$$
On the other hand, for conditional convergence, nothing will change for the singularities at $x=0$ and $x=1$, because the integrand does *not* oscillate around these points. Hence the condition $\max\{\alpha,\beta\}<2$ is necessary. However, as $x\to\infty$ the integrand *oscillates*, meaning that the integral might converge conditionally but not absolutely in some cases. The integral behaves like
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha+\beta}}dx
$$
and an integration by part argument shows that this is conditionally convergent if and only if $\alpha+\beta>0$. To conclude, the original integral is conditionally convergent if and only if
$$
\max\{\alpha,\beta\}<2,
$$
since $\min\{\alpha,\beta\}>0$ is given.

Comment: Thank you. With this, I was able to solve the absolute convergence

Comment: Now, for the conditional convergence I tried to do it using integration by parts, choosing u=$\frac{1}{x^\alpha|1-x|^\beta}$ and dv=$\sin \pi x$ but I'm not sure that this can help. Any hint?

Comment: @Marc for conditional convergence the only thing that might cause trouble is x = infinity. Try your integration by parts technique first on simple things like sin(x)/x.

Comment: Why doesn't 0 and 1 cause trouble in the conditional convergence?

Comment: @Marc their behaviour is the same as their absolute convergence

Comment: In the absolute convergence I found that $\alpha, \beta < 2, \alpha+\beta >1$. But It can happend that in the conditional convergence $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were bigger than 2. Right? So why I don't have to take 0 and 1 into account when considering which values cause trouble?

Comment: @Marc I mean no trouble in the sense that they are straightforward to treat. Not saying that the integrals are always convergent.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I don't understand why did they gave problem to evaluate the absolute convergence bit not the conditional convergence

Comment: What I meant was that once you treated the absolute convergence for x=0 and x=1, the conditional convergence is the same for these points.